# CSS JS scrolling issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I am using Perfect Scrollbar JQuery. On the page is a `div` with `overflow: auto`, and `position: relative`. Inside the `div` is a `table` with `position: absolute`. Scrolling is horizontal, everything  scrolls without problem.

When i click on the overflow div the scroll position is reset to left. But when i first scroll and then click, everything is ok.

What is causing reset of scroll when click?

Comment: Can you provide some code in as [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or in a snipplet?

Comment: not possible its in phonegap

Comment: using jquery could be part of the codebase and the question should be tagged with it

Comment: Nothing much - just compacted the CSS pieces.